# How to view the list of files in AWS S3 using Vuejs API?

Tags: amazon-s3, vuejs2

I upload the files by referring https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9x5LGaL2W7E.But I don't find any reference videos or links to view the files in the bucket with **access key and secret key** not with **userID and Password**. I am specially looking forward to develop this API in **Vue.Js(VUE 2)**
Navigate me.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Use CLI for local debugging and setup classic secure HTTP flow for the rest (like any classic API usage).

Comment: Can you suggest me, any video links or code snippet. Because I am beginner in this field. Thanks!

Comment: The link I gave in my answer is already the one I recommend.

Comment: No, You are helping us with commands, But I have to implement with VUE code.Thanks!

Comment: Then you can use my first comment under your question. You need to check the doc to find out how to open a specific bucket with the proper right etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could somehow achieve that but the best solution is probably to use the AWS CLI and run something like `s3 ls` on your given bucket.

Here is the reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/